# How to search values that begin or end with another value that contains % and _ chars?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Consider the following tables :

```
 drop table if exists testA;
 drop table if exists testB;
 create table testA ( id int, testX varchar(255) );
 create table testB ( id int, testY varchar(255) );
 insert into testA values ( 1, 'this is a test%' );
 insert into testB values ( 1, 'test%' );
 insert into testA values ( 1, 'a test% this is' );
```

This result in :

```
mysql>  select * from testA;
+------+-----------------+
| id   | testX           |
+------+-----------------+
|    1 | this is a test% |
|    1 | a test% this is |
+------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql>  select * from testB;
+------+-------+
| id   | testY |
+------+-------+
|    1 | test% |
+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

How do I get values from the testA table that **end with** the testB value ?

This query :

```
SELECT tA.testX
FROM testA tA
JOIN testB tB USING (id)
WHERE tA.testX LIKE CONCAT('%', tB.testY);
```

Returns the whole results :

```
+-----------------+
| testX           |
+-----------------+
| this is a test% |
| a test% this is |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

This sounds logic of course, because `CONCAT('%', tB.testY)` will return '%test%'. But in my app, I have complex values at the right side of LIKE, containing function calls and mix of columns and strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my solution :

```
SELECT tA.testX
FROM testA tA JOIN testB tB USING (id)
WHERE RIGHT(tA.testX, LENGTH(tB.testY)) = tB.testY
```

Give me :

```
+-----------------+
| testX           |
+-----------------+
| this is a test% |
+-----------------+
```

You can do it with :

- [LEFT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) if you need a string that begin with a value (`LIKE 'xxx%'`).
- [RIGHT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) if you need to search a string that end with a value (`LIKE '%xxx'`)
- [LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) if you need to search a string that contains a value (`LIKE '%xxx%'`)

I post it in case somebody will find that useful.